# Spoof my location in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, geolocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to set my current location manually on Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/498399/is-there-a-way-to-set-my-current-location-manually-on-windows-8)

Is it possible to spoof a location in Windows 8. The motivation is for testing some Windows 8 location querying software.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Since you added that it is a web app, the only way would be using anything that modifies your public IP address:

- [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network)
- [Public](https://www.google.com/search?q=public%20proxy)/private proxy
- [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/)

**OLD ANSWER**

You can do that with visual studio:

[image]

Source: [mvark.blogspot.it](http://mvark.blogspot.it/2012/10/geolocation-spoofing-with-windows-8.html)

Comment: Is this the emulator? I don't have the source for this program that I want to see the different location, or rather it is a web app.