# Windows 8 showing wrong location

Tags: windows-8, geolocation

Windows 8 is showing the wrong location in some apps which are location-sensitive, putting me 300 miles or so away. How can I correct this problem?

Comment: Are you using 3G?

Comment: I suspect this is a duplicate of another question. Please see here for a more information. http://superuser.com/questions/498399/is-there-a-way-to-set-my-current-location-manually-on-windows-8

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464919.aspx), location can be determined from the sources such as:

- Wi-Fi triangulation
- IP address resolution
- Cell phone tower triangulation
- Global Position System (GPS)

---

*If your sources are either Wi-Fi or, if you only have a wired network connection, read on:*

> The Windows Location Provider uses data from **Wi-Fi** access points to calculate latitude and longitude. Locations calculated from Wi-Fi data are accurate to within **350 meters** in urban areas.
>
> When Wi-Fi data is not available, the Windows Location Provider uses **IP address** resolution to get approximate location with an accuracy of **50 kilometers**.

If your location data is coming over GPS or some other source, please provide further details.